# Get root element using jsonpath based on sub elements condition

Tags: java, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I am working with the Jayway JsonPath library to obtain the correct 'id' from below JSON where my `phoneNumbers` type is 'iPhone'.

In general, I would like to know how to find something from the root element of a block when a specific condition is specified in the sub-JSON objects.

I tried below expressions that select the block associated with iPhone type and also a list of ids respectively, but I am not able to get to the root element `id` belonging to the JSON object where my phone type is iPhone. Can someone please guide me? I need to get the `id` as 1 for this question.

To get the list of ids: `$[*].id`

To get the json object corresponding to iPhone type: `$[*].phoneNumbers[?(@.type=='iPhone')]`

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "phoneNumbers": [
            {
                "type": "iPhone",
                "number": "0123-4567-8888"
            },
            {
                "type": "home",
                "number": "0123-4567-8910"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "phoneNumbers": [
            {
                "type": "x",
                "number": "0123-4567-8888"
            },
            {
                "type": "y",
                "number": "0123-4567-8910"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: This works for me using Jayway's JsonPath [here](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/). What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your expression to look deeper.

First, find the objects that have an iPhone in the phone numbers list. Then just select the IDs.

Try `$[?(@.phoneNumbers[*].type=="iPhone")].id`.

---

**Edit**

It looks like the [Java JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) library (I think you're using this) supports a number of functions.  It doesn't list a `contains()`, but you might try the `anyof` operator:

`$[?(@.phoneNumbers[*].type anyof ["iPhone"])].id`

Note that this is definitely implementation-specific and will likely not work with any other library.

Comment: I tried your suggestion here - https://jsonpath.com/ but it didn't give me any result. Kindly let me know if you tested this expression elsewhere and it worked so that I can validate.

Comment: Yeah, there are some nuances in that expression that probably aren't widely supported.  I'll try to think of another way to do it.