# Getting a value from a JSON object using JSONPath

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have the following JSON and I need to get the plain name value using JSONPath:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "code": "ABC",
            "metadata": 
                {
                    "id": "111",
                    "data": "2020"
                }

        },
        
        {
            "code": "123",
            "metadata": 
                {
                    "id": "222",
                    "data": "2018"
                }

        },
        
        {
            "code": "XYZ",
            "metadata": 
                {
                    "id": "555",
                    "data": "2018"
                }

        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get the value of a variable "code" via "id".
Expression that I used is `$.data[?(@.metadata.id == '222')].code` to get the "code"="123". But it doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That should work. Could you please show your code?

Comment: @ChristianBaumann, the code is not available to me, I can only enter expressions. Are there any alternatives to this expression?

Comment: The expression does work.

Comment: Seems to be the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/q/63470519/878701

Comment: It may be more of an issue of expression support in the library you're using.  Some libraries don't have support for detailed expressions like this.